# how to recursively insert a node at a certain index in a linked list

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

I am sort of still new at programming so be generous on your explanations. I'm having trouble implementing the insertAt method recursively. Basically what I need it to do is to insert Object elem into the index of the list without using any loops.

```
public class ListInterfaceImplementation implements ListInterface{

private ListNode first;
private ListNode last;
private ListNode current;
private int size = 0;

public ListInterfaceImplementation(){
}

public ListInterface insertAt(int index, Object elem) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ListNode cur = new ListNode(current);
    if(index < 0){
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    if(elem == null){
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    if(index == 0){
        ListNode node = new ListNode(elem);
        node.getNext() = current.getNext();
        current.getNext() = node;
        size++;
        return this;
    }
    cur = current.getNext();
    return insertAt(index -1, elem);

}
```

This is what I have so far.

Comment: Hint:  what are you doing with "cur"?

Comment: is that a hint that I should be trying something different and get rid of cur completely? I was hoping I could use it to keep track of the current node in the list while decrement the index until it gets to the desired index in the list. I'm just not sure if this is the correct way to use cur. I'm also getting hung up on the if(index==0) loop where i have the pointer assignments... what am I supposed to use as variables when assigning the pointers?

Comment: You are assigning a value to that variable, but you never use it later.  I was assuming that was an oversight.  What's the purpose of the variable if you don't use it?

Comment: Regarding assigning the pointers, you need setter methods, such as setNext(ListNode node).

Comment: I have a ListNode class with all of my getter and setter methods. Do you think posting that class as well would be beneficial?

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

```
if(elem == null){
        throw new NullPointerException();
```

This should presumably also be an out-of-bounds exception (since you're going to get this if you run off the end of the list)

```
private ListNode current;
```

This should not be global - you want the entire state to be contained within the recursion

Generally, the logic should be:

```
insertAt(list, index)
  if index == 0, append the list to the node to insert and return the result
  else return firstElementOfList + insertAt(listMinusFirstElement, index-1)
```

That is, our recursion step simplifies by reducing the list and the index.